# How to get current cell signal strength?

Tags: android, telephony

I would like to store the cell signal strength, and I do it like this:

```
private class GetRssi extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        Variables.signal = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();


    }

}
```

Okay but this only runs if it changes. I need the current signal strength.

Is there a method to just ask for the current signal strength?

Comment: If you register this listener when your app starts then you have the current signal strength. It won't change until you get called by the listener again at which point you can update your internal variable storing the strength.

Comment: Like Ryan says...if you keep track of the current signal strength then you will always know what it currently is!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is [getAllCellInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getAllCellInfo()) method in TelephonyManager added in API 17 that could be good solution. Example of use:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// for example value of first element
CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Comment: Good one but i use lower api, i still voted for the answer thanks.

Comment: Just a heads up: It seems that some devices (looking at you Samsung) don't properly implement getAllCellInfo() and will return null.

Comment: You will also need to add this permission code to your manifest...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: @ ban-geoengineering coarse location or fine location ?

Comment: My IDE is telling me I need the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission (which also requires `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`)

Comment: item get(0) may not be of type CellInfoGSM.  So you might want to just call getAllCellInfo and traverse the list and use getClass on each entry to properly cast.

Answer (score 29):

CellSignalStrengthGsm() is added Added in API level 17

CellSignalStrengthGsm().getDbm() will give you the signal strength as dBm

```
 private static String getSignalStrength(Context context) throws SecurityException {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String strength = null;
    List<CellInfo> cellInfos = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();   //This will give info of all sims present inside your mobile
    if(cellInfos != null) {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cellInfos.size() ; i++) {
            if (cellInfos.get(i).isRegistered()) {
                if (cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                    CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfos.get(i);
                    CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrengthWcdma = cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
                    strength = String.valueOf(cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getDbm());
                } else if (cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                    CellInfoGsm cellInfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) cellInfos.get(i);
                    CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
                    strength = String.valueOf(cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm());
                } else if (cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) cellInfos.get(i);
                    CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
                    strength = String.valueOf(cellSignalStrengthLte.getDbm());
                } else if (cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                    CellInfoCdma cellInfoCdma = (CellInfoCdma) cellInfos.get(i);
                    CellSignalStrengthCdma cellSignalStrengthCdma = cellInfoCdma.getCellSignalStrength();
                    strength = String.valueOf(cellSignalStrengthCdma.getDbm());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return strength;
}
```

Please note that above code will return `strength` of the last cell in the list.

You can learn more from:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo.html

CellInfoCdma, CellInfoGsm, CellInfoLte, CellInfoWcdma are the subclasses of CellInfo. Which gives all information related to your mobile network.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I just added the `if` branch for the `CellinfoCdma` too.

Comment: You could have edited the answer to add the additional `CellInfoCdma`

Comment: @Carlos.V That applies to you also, you could have edited the answer. -_-

Comment: @AnanthRajSingh no, thanks! :), you could also edited it jaja

Comment: @AnanthRajSingh nice.. [you deserve it](https://www.lacasadelaeducadora.com/img/producto/53SI.png)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a SDK version > 28, you can use getSignalStrength() function like so:

```
telephonyManager.getSignalStrength().getLevel();
```

Here is a fully implemented function:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

...

int getCellularSignalStrength()  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {

        if(telephonyManager == null)
            telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) common.appContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        return telephonyManager.getSignalStrength().getLevel();
    }
    else
    {
        logRecorder.addWarningLog("Cannot read signal lvl on API lvl " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: For simple use, this answer is much more concise.