# Android: How can I determine if an application starts with no or low GSM signal?

Tags: android, callback, gsm, signal-strength, phone-state-listener

I have written a piece of Android code that registers a `PhoneStateListener` and
reports the GSM signal strength values when there are changes, through the
`onSignalStrengthsChanged` callback. Everything works fine, but I want to have
the initial signal strength before the first change occurs.. Is there a way
to find out the GSM signal strength before the end of the `onCreate` method
(see the commented lines at the end of the code)?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int mStrength;
private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
private TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
             super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
             int currStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
             mStrength = currStrength;

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "signal:" + String.valueOf(mStrength),
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }               
    };

    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
               PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);

    // What is value of GSM signal here? ...
    // Log.d("SignalStrength:", "??");

}

}
```

Comment: I found this, that describe what I want for the API level 17: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529744/how-to-get-current-cell-signal-strength
But how can I do it for older API versions, e.g. API level 8?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use [this SignalStrength class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html) which was added in API level 7?

Comment: I tried it, but the you cannot use a SignalStrength constructor.. The constructor is not visible.. You have to make a listener to use it as I have post in my question. Check this link also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/oAMIr4br8hc .
But, I want a way to get Signal strength value without registering a listener.