# Settings an int value with a method

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am no Java developer, but I am trying to add some more data to a Cordova plugin for Android.

I don't understand why this is not permitted? Here I am trying to set the value of asu witht he method.

```
int asu = getSignalStrength();

The method below:

  int signalStrength = 0;


  private int getSignalStrength(CellSignalStrength signal) {
    signalStrength = signal.getAsuLevel();
    return signalStrength;
  }
```

The error below:

> method getSignalStrength in class Sim cannot be applied to given
>   types;
>         int asu = getSignalStrength();

Are they not both int types? What  am I dogin wrong

Comment: You aren't passing in the parameter.  They aren't optional.

Comment: Your function is needed a parameter "signal" to be called. Why are you not sending at the time of calling ? Please share more specific code if you are not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure what to pass it, Im guessing type CellSignalStrength, but not usre how to pass it, or initialise it first? Im guessing I should pass CellSignalStrength as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add parameter while calling getSignalStrength();
Like below -

int asu = getSignalStrength(signal);

Comment: I assume the parameter would be of type CellSignalStrength? How would I pass that? Just as CellSignalStrength or must it first be initiated somehow?

Comment: You have to create object of CellSignalStrength and pass it as parameter

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but how? Tried this, obviously wrong. CellSignalStrength signal = CellSignalStrength;

Comment: Check my answer, you have to create a new instance first.

Comment: CellSignalStrength signal = new CellSignalStrength();

Comment: CellSignalStrength is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: I do this: import android.telephony.CellSignalStrength;

Comment: create object like this - > TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
    CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();  

    int asu = getSignalStrength(cellSignalStrengthGsm);

Answer (score 1):

First of all create a new instance of CellSignalStrength:

```
 final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Then you can pass it in the method as a parameter

```
int asu = getSignalStrength(cellSignalStrengthGsm);
```

Comment: I tried that,  CellSignalStrength is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: I imported it like this: import android.telephony.CellSignalStrength;

Comment: Is there any child of CellSignalStrength ?

Comment: ?Known Direct Subclasses
CellSignalStrengthCdma, CellSignalStrengthGsm, CellSignalStrengthLte, CellSignalStrengthWcdma

Comment: So which one do you think you need ? You can use these subclasses and get information about signal strength. As these are not abstract, you can create an instance of these.

Comment: Wouldnt it depend on what type of connection you have at the time?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it depends on the type of connection. That's why separate classes are available for use.

Comment: This might get you an idea:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529744/how-to-get-current-cell-signal-strength

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share what it looked like in the end:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


      List<CellInfo> cellInfos = manager.getAllCellInfo();   //This will give info of all sims present inside your mobile 
      int asu = 0;
      if(cellInfos!=null){
        for (int i = 0 ; i<cellInfos.size(); i++){
           if (cellInfos.get(i).isRegistered()){
                if (cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                    CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) manager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                    CellSignalStrength strength = cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
                    asu = getSignalStrength(strength);
                } else if(cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                    CellInfoGsm cellInfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) manager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                    CellSignalStrength strength = cellInfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
                    asu = getSignalStrength(strength);
                } else if(cellInfos.get(i) instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                    CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) manager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                    CellSignalStrength strength = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
                    asu = getSignalStrength(strength);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```